# Finding the least number of terms.

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Find the least number of terms needed for the sum of the series $$\sum_{i=1}^n (3-2i)$$ to be less than $-100$.

**Solution:**

$$\sum_{i=1}^n (3-2i) = 3n - 2\sum_{i=1}^n i = 2n - n^2 $$

Because it is less than $-100$,

$2n - n^2 < -100$

And I'm stuck here, since n became two imaginary numbers.

Comment: It should be $2n-n^2$.

Comment: It looks like you’ve added the second sum instead of subtracting it.

Comment: Should say:  since you'll have to test values anyway (this is an integer problem, not a continuous one), I'd say it's easier to simply compute the sum for various $n$.  That only takes a few seconds.

Comment: I think I made a mess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correction:
$$\sum_{i=1}^ni=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\Rightarrow3n-2\sum_{i=1}^ni=3n-n(n+1)=-n^2+2n.$$
Also, note why a solution must exist in this case. As you increase $n$ i.e. the number of terms, the sum of your series decreases. (Can you see why? Either graph it to check or look at the derivative). Hence, there should exist the first time your sum reaches $-100$ or less than $-100$. After this, the sum will only decrease further.

Cross-check with what you had gotten earlier. The sum is only increasing. Is it possible for it to reach $-100$ at all?

Solution:
$$-n^2+2n<-100\Rightarrow0<n^2-2n-100.$$
You can solve this in two ways. Find $A$ and $B$ such that $n^2-2n-100=(n-A)(n-B)$ select the positive solution (either of $A$ or $B$ would be negative since, $AB=-100$). Also, the polynomial takes strictly positive values on all $n$ except $[A,B]$.
Note. Suppose $A$ is the positive solution. If $A$ is not an integer, then the answer is the smallest integer larger than $A$ (since you want $n$ to be an integer). If $A$ is an integer then observe that the strict positive condition is not satisfied. So, your answer should be $A+1$.

Another way to solve it is to observe:
$$0<n^2-2n-100=n^2-2n+1-101=(n-1)^2-101=N_0^2-101$$
Simply replace $(n-1)$ by $N_0$ and find the minimum squared value greater than $101$ (which is achieved at $N_0=11\Rightarrow n-1=11\Rightarrow n=12$. You can cross-check too!)

Comment: Your completion of the square is incorrect. Should be $(n-1)^2 + \cdots$.

Comment: @Deepak right my bad. thanks a lot!